Allow notification when key is expired in dragonflydb
I would like to allow notify-keyspace-events in DragonflyDB for events, when key is expired. Generally, DragonflyDB doesn't support notifications. But I have found this github issue:
DragonflyDB github
In last comment, it seems that they are supporting notify-keyspace-event Ex.
DragonflyDB is running via docker (on Mac OS) with this command:
docker run -p 6379:6379 --ulimit memlock=-1 docker.dragonflydb.io/dragonflydb/dragonfly

Also I have tried to add flag inside command
docker run -p 6379:6379 --ulimit memlock=-1 --notify-keyspace-events Ex docker.dragonflydb.io/dragonflydb/dragonfly

but I get this error: unknown flag: --notify-keyspace-events
Also, I have tried to allow it in config, via redis-cli, even dragonflydb is stated that they are not supporting it. Anyway, I tried it.
CONFIG SET --notify-keyspace-events Ex

But also, I get this error: ERR Unknown option or number of arguments for CONFIG SET - 'notify-keyspace-events'
So, my question is, how to allow notifications for key events in dragonflydb?
Thank you

localhost:6385> config set notify_keyspace_events eX
OK

works with underscores instead
